# Error in Experience Profile due to missing 'Accept-Language' in Server variables

Tags: xconnect

I am getting an error in my SC10 AKS instance in experience profile when I click on a contact:

```
URL http://testabc.com/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/{9cc8524k-b9dd-0000-0000-066f49mf968eg/image?w=170&h=170

Exception System.Exception: Language must be specified using Accept-Language header.
at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.NegotiateLanguageFilter.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I see in the Server variables, **Accept-Language** is missing.

Any idea from where Accept-Language Server variable is created?
How can I fix it?

Comment: `Accept-Language` HTTP header is usually added by your browser when it sends a request. Do you see this header under Request Headers in the browser Network tab?

Comment: yes, Its present in request header but not in Server variables.

Comment: I have one more instance where its present in Server  variables and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for checking, do you have any rewrite rules that can be removing headers or server variables?

Comment: No, there is no such redirect rule. I feel its something related to AKS ingress settings but I am not sure. I'll update here if I find a solution.